# Internet connection slow in linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, connection, slow-connection

I have a problem with my new internet connection. This is a symmetric 500Mbs connection but i only get 50M in my linux computer. In windows I get 500Mb for up and down with other computer. 
I know that the problem is in my ethernet connection in linux because my speed in ethernet card is 100Mb. I don't know why.

This is the ethernet card values (it supports 1Gb)

```
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                           drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

I tried with ethtool but when I try to change to 1000Mb/s with

```
$ sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 speed 1000 duplex full

Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: no
```

but I get no link connection

If I try to up the enp3s0 the 1000Mb speed disappears and I get 100M again

```
$ sudo ifup enp3s0 

$ 
Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
enp3s0: 100 Mbit, half duplex, link ok
$
```

I don't know what else to try.

Thanks

Comment: This really belongs on superuser.com. Its likely a cabling fault - 100megabit requires 2 pairs, gigabit 4. pairs. Uf not you should advise the make and model if your card (maybe driver issue?) and check and confirm the port its plugged into (what happens if you swap switch ports with the other PC).

Comment: 03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)

Comment: If this is a server Replace that card. Realtek are the worst of the worst. They have detection and driver issues, and are resource heavy. It could well be a driver issue - see https://unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
$ sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 autoneg on
```